# Missing ; in Android Studio with jni

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use JNI in Android Studio. But, after I execute the javah command the stub is generated with the error: Missing ; after JNICALL

Comment: So what's the problem? Your header file isn't getting created? Your method calls aren't working? Your header file has wrong data in it?

Comment: Sometimes a warning shows the true problem while the errors just show the consequences—maybe something like can't find included header jni.h.

Comment: The error just disappeared. I was unable to identify the reason.